# Cannot access to the remote Linux server after activating firewall

Tags: firewall, remote-desktop

I accidentally log out from my remote Linux ubuntu server after enabling firewall. When I am trying to connect with my SSH it gives me 'port22: operation timed out'. Is there any ways to connect to the server again?

Comment: That depends on your firewall settings. The purpose of the firewall is to filter traffic, after all, so if you didn't allow connections on port 22, you'll need an alternative way to connect to the server, physically or remotely.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I didn't allow connections on port 22. What is the alternative way to connect to the server remotely? Can you suggest me any methods by any chance?

Comment: Since you're asking, I'm assuming that means you haven't enabled/set up any other means of connecting remotely, so if it's your own physical server, you'll most probably have to pay it a visit. If it's some virtual machine hosted by a provider, they might offer some interface for you to reach the server.